# Flyway set location In java

Tags: java, flyway

I'm just using the latest version, and reading the documentation I cannot find a way programmatically to specify a flyway where are my migration v*_description.sql files that I have in the file-system.  I cannot use location since I would like to use the Java API to do It.

There's an DSL to do that in your API or command-line is the only way?.

Regards

Comment: Have you checked the `FLYWAY_LOCATIONS` parameter (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/envvars#FLYWAY_LOCATIONS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the locations of your db migration files in Maven, Gradle or Java API.

Maven:

```
<flyway.locations>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration</flyway.locations>
```

Gradle:

```
locations = ['classpath:db/migration']
```

Java:

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(databaseUrl + databaseSchema, databaseUser, databasePassword);
flyway.setLocations("DB_MIGRATION_LOCATIONS");
flyway.migrate();
```